# Indicate vs Indicates

Tags: verb-agreement, transitive-verbs

My question is whether `indicate` or `indicates` should be used in the following sentence:

> The test ids ARB1 and ARB2 indicate(s) that two different samples were used, rather than representing different test methods.

My colleague is of the view that the subject "test ids ARB1 and ARB2" is plural, and hence the verb would be in it's plural form (without an s) "indicate". I agree with him, but ultimately we're unsure of ourselves hence the question here.

Comment: You leave no room for doubt in the question itself. Can't see why there should be any further confusion.

Comment: 'IDs' has a plural 's'; there are two IDs; the sentence says that two different samples were used. How could the subject of 'indicate' be anything but plural? As @Pkjmm says you leave no room for doubt in your question.

Comment: We felt that using "indicate" sounded wrong. I suppose we were simply (incorrectly) second guessing ourselves. Shall I flag this question?

Comment: If desired it could be reworded to use *indicates*, e.g., "The use of these test IDs indicates that..."